# Finding the characteristic curves of the given PDE which is passing through the given point.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to find the number of characteristic curves of the PDE $(x^2+2y)u_{xx}+(y^3-y+u)u_{yy}+x^2(y-1)u_{xy}+3u_{x}+u=0,$ passing through the point $x =1,  y= 1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262132/the-number-of-characteristic-curves-of-the-pde